# How to have different possible inputs based on a condition in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I recently got to know about the saturation port in the integrator block. My output from the integrator block (say x) must be, let's say between -a (lower limit) to +a (higher limit). Assuming my input is a step input, here's how I want it to happen. If x reaches +a, I want to change the input to a negative step input. If x reaches -a, I want to change the input to a positive step input.

I have no idea how to go about this. Here's what I've done till now.
I used an if else block with input as the saturation port and having two If Action blocks for each condition. Now the output of the action blocks must be the input. But I have now two action blocks. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like bang-bang control!

Try using triggers, maybe on for each -a (falling) and +a(rising)? x is your control signal. [Triggered Subsystems](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/triggered-subsystems.html)